# Apache as Proxy server insert html to every traffic pass through proxy

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, layout

I'm using Apache 2.4 on Windows, i config apache as a proxy server. and i try to use mod_layout 5.1 to insert html,php to footer on every http traffic pass through proxy.

[This is my network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtmHL.gif)

- What i want is, if some one in my LAN network try to open a http website aka google.com, he will get a floating footer banner on his google search. ( i know google.com is https, this just for example. )
- The Apache proxy server on this situation act as a proxy, and though mod_proxy and mod_layout, insert  floating .html footer to any traffic pass though.
- In my config, i can only set  floating .html footer to site that i hosted on my apache, the other site on internet can't be insert.

My question is: CAN YOU INSERT A HTML TO ANY TRAFFIC GO THOUGH APACHE PROXY SERVER BY USING MOD_LAYOUT AND MOD_PROXY?

THIS IS MY APACHE CONFIG ON MOD PROXY

```
<IfModule mod_layout.c>
AddOutputFilter LAYOUT html 
AddOutputFilter LAYOUT htm 
AddOutputFilter LAYOUT shtml 
AddOutputFilter LAYOUT shtm 
AddOutputFilter LAYOUT cgi 
AddOutputFilter LAYOUT php 
LayoutFooter "C:/xampp/apache/cgi-bin/footer.php"
</IfModule>
```

The problem is, i can't find any clear tutorial for this situation. Although it is too simple for all answers on this forum, but none have a clear and working answer.

PS:so please dont comment if::: - i've tried many way, none of it working, so please dont comment if you don't know a working solution (using nginx header output, mod_sed apache, Squid proxy with icap ecap server, squid with greaspoon,  Apache Handlers, CGI script. Apache filter, mod_substitute, even mod_layout.... i can only add footer html to site that hosted by my apache, the site that hosted by another server pass though my proxyserver cant be insert.

- i'm living in Asia, so please don't give advice as a lawyer that i shoudn't do this. I only want to know is there is any solution for this problem, for education purpose only.